# Zip function in python 3.2.3 not working as hoped

Tags: python, function, matrix, zip, transpose

I am trying to define a function that transposes a matrix. This is my code:

```
def Transpose (A):
    B = list(zip(*A))
    return B
```

Now when I call the function somewhere in the program like such:

```
Matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Transpose(Matrix)
print(Matrix)
```

The matrix comes out unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Your function returns a new value that does not affect your matrix (`zip` does not change it's parameters). You are not doing anything wrong, that is the correct way of doing things.
Just change it to:

```
print(Transpose(Matrix))
```

or

```
Matrix = Transpose(Matrix)
```

Note: You really should be using lower-case names for your functions and variables.